# Posting non-free code on SO

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I recently came across a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218910/how-to-add-extra-comment-field-in-dreamveations-v4-0-quick-checkout#comment50440499_31218910) which requested the OP post the complete code for a non-free software extension.

Stack Exchange terms of service specifically states:

> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party, (b) reveals any trade secret, unless Subscriber owns the trade secret or has the owner’s permission to post it, (c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another

When I flagged the comment to indicate this my flag was declined.  I'm a bit confused about this since it is direct contradiction to the site policy.

Should my flag have been declined or was this possibly an oversight?

Comment: The moderators refuse to be the license enforcement police for other companies.  They can file a DMCA takedown by themselves.  Nor will they block questions about other non-free products like Excel and SQL Server.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest blocking a question about commercial software - just violating our own terms of service.  It's not a question of policing for other companies, but one of enforcing our own policies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not up to the site moderators to police things like this.

The copyright owner needs to contact Stack Exchange directly and issue a takedown notice.

If you find things like this and you're **not** the copyright owner then the only thing you can do is bring it to the attention of the copyright owner.

Comment: So "not-constructive" or "too chatty" are legit reasons to moderate but not a violation of terms of service?  That seems odd

Comment: @billynoah: Who violated the terms? And are you really qualified to judge that? Also, note that iff the mods/SE actively enforced some peoples IP, they would expose themselves to loads of legal liability. Nobody needs that kind of hurt.

Comment: @Deduplicator i can certainly understand that.  just that it seems like we should not allow users to encourage one another to violate our own defined terms.

Comment: @billynoah: Those terms are there to protect SE and anyone using things posted here.

Comment: With the kinds of comments I've seen removed because they were off topic I'm shocked that a comment saying "Hey, do this illegal thing" is allowed to stand

Comment: @billynoah: So you are asserting that the OP definitely cannot have or get the right to do so, and you have legal proof? Do you know without doubt who he is?

Comment: well you've got a point there.  She definitely does not work for Dreamvention, but I can agree that it's possible she could get the rights to post their code.  Having dealt with them directly however, I can tell you that it's highly unlikely.

Comment: Perhaps. But it's really not our responsibility to sort out

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.

The terms of service exists primarily to prevent Stack Exchange from being liable for the misconduct of their users.  So if a user post proprietary code illegally, that user faces the legal ramifications of such an act, and Stack Exchange can point to the terms of service to say "we told them not to do that."

You already did your due diligence with your own [comments warning the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1767412/billynoah) to not violate other (external) terms of use by posting the code in question.  That was fine and perhaps even helpful.

---

Now as to why your flag was declined.  The comment you flagged was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218910/how-to-add-extra-comment-field-in-dreamveations-v4-0-quick-checkout#comment50440499_31218910):

> and with such a short code snippet. it's really hard to determine what the problem is, please post the full code of both the template and the controller

that's a very constructive comment.  It's not offensive, non-constructive, irrelevantly chatty, or obsolete.  It's an honest comment asking for the OP to add more code to the question since they believe the problem exists in code not included in the question.

If people really thought posting that code was a bad idea, your contradictory warning comment would have a lot of comment upvotes.  Regardless, this comment doesn't fit any of the normal reasons for flagging a comment.  And [ChrisF's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302870/4320665) seems to imply that pleading your case in a custom flag is not one they can take action on anyway, so a custom flag is also out.

Comment: Thanks - in regards to the theory of comment upvotes, bear in mind that the question itself was only viewed approximately **zero** times between the time I made that comment and when I posted this question.

I think we should have a "this violates the terms" flag.  imo, if we are taking the time to remove unhelpful content, we should also be interested in removing content that violates the site rules.

Apparently that's just not how it is and I can accept that.  This fact is new to me though and hence the reason for my question

Comment: also, i agree the comment itself was somewhat helpful, but should be rephrased in a way which doesn't say, *hey do this thing which is not allowed*.

Comment: If my comment asking an OP to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) was removed, I would be the one posting a meta question. Answerers and moderators are not responsible for the licensing of the code provided in a question. If someone posts a question about code, it is assumed that they have license to do so. If it turns out that the OP did not have license to use the code in that way, it is the responsibility of the owners of the license to take action. Questions have to be on-topic, correctly licensed or not. @billynoah